# Is it ok to use AsyncTask in Android ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

Is AsyncTask safe for background jobs like database requests or will it have issues such as memory leakage? Is it safe to use in ViewModel?

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to what the latest AndroidStudio tells you, you are safe to use AsyncTask anywhere you want as long as you handle it correctly. That means if you fire it from an activity or fragment, you should cancel your AsyncTask when the activity/fragment destroys. The reason they warn against it is because often AsyncTask has a reference to the activity. If the AsyncTask is taking forever and the activity destroys, the AsyncTask is still running and holding a reference to the Activity. This hard reference keeps the Activity from being garbage collected and you will still get any AsyncTask callbacks once it completes into the destroyed Activity. But this can easily be avoided simply by making it lifecycle aware: call AsyncTask.cancel(true). Architecturally, that's up to you to decide.

TLDR; just be sure to cancel your asynctask when it's not needed anymore.